# Laravel: 404 error instead of usual exceptions

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have two routes.

The second stopped working so I added the first one (which works perfectly).

**Routes file**

```
Route::get('/cms/index', function () {
    return view('cms-templates/index');
});

Route::get('/cms', function () {
    return view('cms-templates/index');
    // tried return redirect('/cms/index')
    // tried return hello world
});
```

The problem is it doesn't matter what I try to `return` in the second route, it always throws a page with error **404 Not Found ------ nginx/ver** instead of the **NotFoundHttpException** or **InvalidArgumentException** that usually come when not finding route or file (which still happens with which other route)

Comment: View uses the dot notation syntax, not slashes. Try `return view('cmd-templates.index');`

Comment: Check for any middleware in web.php or in kernel.php's middleware which doing this?

Comment: @aynber Changed the syntax, nothing's changed. It doesn't matter what I return in the second route, it throws that 404 Not Found page

Comment: Do any other routes work? Is that your whole routes file?

Comment: Every other route works, even the ones using controllers. If I break **any other** route on purpose, I get the **NotFoundHttpException**. Only `/cms` throws the 404.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Route::get('/cms/index', function () {
    return view('cms-templates.index'); //cms-templates should be a folder with a blade called index
});
```

Anyway you're trying to return the same view for two differents Routes?.

Also you can call to a controller and her function using this:

```
Route::get('/cms/index','namecontroller@function');
```

Feel free to ask if have any doubt.

Comment: I am trying to get the second route to throw **anything** other than that 404 page. Changed the syntax and everything is the same, can't even return "hello world!"

Comment: Hard to understand, like I understand you made a blade to 404 error ? Or you want to show hello world when you go to /cms?

Comment: Puedes explicármelo en español y te entenderé mejor, creo.

Comment: @Brunouno prueba a poner las rutas al revés, primero la de /cms y luego /cms/index

Comment: The second route was the original one, so my end user could just write `{sitename}/cms` and land on the cms index page. It now throws that **404** page, so I added the `/cms/index` as a temporary fix and it works. 

I'd like to go back to the original `/cms` route, but no matter what I do (call for the view, redirect elsewhere, or even just return "hello world"), that **404** remains the only response .

Comment: Try to put first the other route, and next the other one.

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153491/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-brunouno).